# Whenever i paint, it's on the opposite side

Tags: texture-painting

when I paint on one side of an object, the colors shows up on the other side
I've tried applying the scale but nothing works

Comment: Have you checked the direction of your normals?  Enable face orientation in overlays dropdown; your mesh should be blue, looking from outside it, not red.

Comment: it is red, how would i fix it? i havent had blender for super long sry.

Comment: In edit mode, select all, then "recalculate normals" operation, probably ctrl n.  If that doesn't fix it, it's probably because of non-manifold geometry ("select non manifold" operation to find) or zero area faces, ie doubled verts.

Comment: it worked thank you so much!!!!!!

Comment: @Blunder nice. I  knew there was a duplicate somewhere but i couldnt find it via google.

Comment: Hi, Liam, and welcome . Glad there's a fix for you. It turns out that this post is a duplicate, as Blunder has pointed out, so it can be closed without harm to the archive.